# MySQL query results export to xml file using external xsd file

Tags: mysql, xml, xsd

I have been searching for a tool or method to export a Mysql query to a xml file, but using an external xsd file.  I have the schema file and I wonder if anyone seen or have used something to build the xml file itself? I have seen many import options, but very little, if any export options.

Comment: it's xml. export in whatever format mysql is providing it in, then use an xslt to transform it to whatever you want.

Comment: true, I was just looking for one tool or a single option.